# index.html rendered by webpack caching does not load well and loses to load scss

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

In my project using webpack configuration, single page "index.html" which has tag for loading css and js with their hashed names. Every deployment a new index.html has defined by webpack caching.

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Caching',
    template: './index.html',
    filename: 'index.html'
}),
```

This index.html is under the folder of dist where css and js with their hashed names stored.

The problem is a new html cannot be loaded properly in browser where old version of html had been called after every new deployment.

So that clients can see broken UI for having inconsistent versions of index.html and css name in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tested all requests for HTTP request for HTML of the page are resided in the browser cache.
Whenever making a request for each HTTP request for HTML, the response is from the browser cache not directly from the server as long as the browser cache is not clear.
We need to get response from server directly for updated content of requested HTML.

Solution :We have the solution for configuring the sever that every response from the server won't be cached in browser. Before taking this advantage, the most important point is that our HTTP request should reach to the server directly (**very importantly not from browser cache). 
After getting the direct response from server, this can guarantee that the response won't be cached in browser and user won't see any broken UI for future because of caching response.

Besides server side configuration, we still need to make explicit request to the server for updated HTML that can get server response including the request body that let browser knows not to store it.

For current situation, the page needs to make explicit request to server to get the status for letting the browser knows not to store the HTML.

To solve this, we change url for getting explicit HTML response from browser. 
This is the only way that solve our current problem.

Anyone who wants to discuss, warmly welcome and open your suggestion.